# Nested Exception handling in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, exception

I am getting the following error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

And to handle this in a controller, I have used the following code:

```
@ExceptionHandler(NestedServletException.class)
public ModelAndView handleServletErrors(){
    System.out.println("Servlet Exception is thrown");
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("error"); 
    mv.addObject("error", "Error encountered while processing reqeust.");
    return mv;
}
```

But this does not handle the exception thrown above. Whereas if I use `NullPointerException` class instead of `NestedServletException`, it works. Since Spring is throwing exception in response to `NullPointerException` shouldn't it be handled by the code above?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the documentation of [`@ExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html):

> Annotation for handling exceptions in specific handler classes and/or handler methods.

This annotation will allow a method to handle exceptions that are thrown by handler methods, i.e. methods that are annotated with `@RequestMapping`. Quoting the [Spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler):

> You can do that with `@ExceptionHandler` methods. When declared within a controller such methods apply to exceptions raised by `@RequestMapping` methods of that contoroller (or any of its sub-classes). You can also declare an `@ExceptionHandler` method within an `@ControllerAdvice` class in which case it handles exceptions from `@RequestMapping` methods from many controllers.

Since the exception thrown by your handler is `NullPointerException`, the exception handler method will handle that specific exception. It will not handle the generic `NestedServletException` that Spring uses to encapsulate servlet exceptions.