# @ExceptionHandler does not work for specific hibernate exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, uitableview, exception

I am trying to catch some *internal* exceptions and then prompt the end-users with nicer messages. But when it comes to this exception:

> Exception StackTrace

```
08/May/2018:20:39:09.947 +0800 ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [] ERROR: update or delete on table "alert_rule" violates foreign key constraint "alert_alert_rule_id_fkey" on table "alert"
  Detail: Key (id)=(58) is still referenced from table "alert".
08/May/2018:20:39:09.977 +0800 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] [] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [alert_alert_rule_id_fkey]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "alert_rule" violates foreign key constraint "alert_alert_rule_id_fkey" on table "alert"
  Detail: Key (id)=(58) is still referenced from table "alert".
```

The `@ExceptionHandler(value = {javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException.class,
                org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class})` seems not working as expected.

I just checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933854/nested-exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) which points out that **specific** exception handler should be handled when used with **general** handler.

And also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221064/spring-exceptionhandler-handling-multiple-kinds-of-exceptions), so **multiple** exceptions can be handled in **one single** handler.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException.class,
            org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class})
    public void constraintViolationException(Exception ex,
                                                      WebRequest req) {
        log.error("Constraint violation while processing {}", req.toString());
    }



    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
    public void unknownException(Exception ex, WebRequest req) {
        log.error("Unknown Internal Exception happens");
    }
}
```

Is there something I missed, thanks for any helpful details.

Comment: clean your classpath and recompile your class then run probably problem with your classpath not updated..

Comment: please add complete stacktrace to identify the problem... it looks like half of the code you have put here....

Comment: @Vikrant I just added more details, what would you say for this case? Thanks for the help~

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to handle a `DataIntegrityViolationException` but your exception handler handles only `ConstraintViolationException`s.

Add the exception type to the handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler({
    javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException.class,
    org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class,
    org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just tried but it won't work either. As I mentioned this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933854/nested-exception-handling-in-spring-mvc), the nested **exception** should be able to be detected and handled.